# Material: Autocomplete options > set selected option

Tags: angular-material

I have a  that has a default value and a dropdown with other values to choose from.
These other values are only loaded once the dropdown is opened. Once loaded, I try to select the option for which the option value equals that of the control.

I illustrated this with [a sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/exhs8r?file=src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html). In this example, the control holds the value 'Shelley', when clicking inside the box, a 'loading' text appears and one second later, the data is loaded and is displayed. This logic can be seen in the `onAutoCompleteOpened` method. It simply after a time-out assigns a new list to our `filteredOptionsSync` variable.

But then I want the option with the text 'Shelley' of the dropdown to be selected as well. So I invoke the method `handleSelection` which eventually calls `option.select()`. This Material method then not only selects 'Shelley', but also closes the box.

I DO NOT WANT THE BOX CLOSED!

I merely wanted 'Shelley' to be selected.

Material also exposes the `optionSelected` event in the `MatAutoComplete` API and the `onSelectionChange` event in the `MatOption` api. But none of these are usefull. They do however notify me that the selection was not a userInteraction, but they do not allow me to 'cancel' the closing.